# Multiple checkbox filter not filtering correct

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, checkbox

I'm working on a piece of code but I'm not able to get it to work.

I have these checkboxes that when I check them then the list gets filtered and the screen gets live updated with AJAX. The multiple filtering works but only if the information is still on the screen. As soon as it's filtered out then it's not coming back. I have a lot of these statements. Do I need to add If / Else statements ?

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=records', 'root', '*******');
$select = 'SELECT *';
$from = ' FROM overboekingen';
$where = ' WHERE TRUE';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');


if (in_array("coulance_happyhome1", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND coulance_happyhome = 1";
}
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome2", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND coulance_happyhome = 2";
}
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome3", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND coulance_happyhome = 3";
}
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome4", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND coulance_happyhome = 4";
}
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome5", $opts)){
    $where .= " AND coulance_happyhome = 5";
}


$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>



</td>
        <td class="tdfilter">                

<label for="coulance_happyhome"><h4>Coulance Happyhome</h4></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome1">Coulance Agent<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome2">Coulance Camping<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome3">Coulance Park<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome4">Coulance    Privatowner<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="coulance_happyhome" name="coulance_happyhome5">Coulance HappyHome<br>

        </td>
        <td class="tdfilter">                

<label for="opmerking"><h4>Opmerking</h4></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="opmerking" name="opmerking">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function makeTable(data){
var tbl_body = "";
$.each(data, function() {
var tbl_row = "";
$.each(this, function(k , v) {
tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
})
tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
})

return tbl_body;
}

function getEmployeeFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
        opts.push(this.name);
    }
    });
return opts;
}

function updateEmployees(opts){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {filterOpts: opts},
        success: function(records){
            $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
        }
    });
}

var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    var opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();
    updateEmployees(opts);
});

updateEmployees();
```

Comment: We definitely need to see more code here. Can you post the form with the checkboxes, and more of the related filtering code?

Comment: There added some code :)

Comment: I think your opts array is being built up, but never reduced. Can you add a console.log statement in your checkboxes.onChange function, and observe the value of opts as you filter results?

Comment: Still there? I posted another answer there... have you tried it out?

Comment: You should use 2 separate file, in the first php file you should keep your php script with the name submit.php and in other page all rest of code like html and ajax code then your code will work properly, bcoz i think your submit.php page is not proper define so you are not getting any output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like:

```
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome1", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR coulance_happyhome = 1";
}
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome2", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR coulance_happyhome = 2";
}
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome3", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR coulance_happyhome = 3";
}
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome4", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR coulance_happyhome = 4";
}
if (in_array("coulance_happyhome5", $opts)){
    $where .= " OR coulance_happyhome = 5";
}
```

Comment: When I try this then the filter stops working completely

Answer (score 0):

I think your opts array is building up but never losing elements once they've been added. Change your checkboxes on change function like so:

```
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    opts.length = 0;
    opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();
    updateEmployees(opts);
});
```